# TWRP mkfs.ntfs Missing

Tags: ntfs

I have a device with MSM8909 (SD 212).  I found a ready-made TWRP image on the internet and I am using it, but it is not in the `mkfs.ntfs` `/sbin` folder required for NTFS formatting.  How can I add it to the TWRP I use and where can I find the required file? I need this because I will be using Windows RT 8/8.1 and Windows 10 ARMv7 via EDK2 UEFI.